# Wordpress conflict with post-views plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am facing an duplicate post with infinite scroll
when i am adding This code to my index.php to order psot by views

```
<?php query_posts('v_sortby=views&amp;v_orderby=desc') ?>
```

the post are repeated again and again

here's the plugin link

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me to was facing such kinds of problem with infinite scroll
so after a bit research i founded this code

```
<?php global $query_string; query_posts($query_string . "&v_sortby=views&;v_orderby=desc"); ?>
```

THis will fix the issue with infinite scroll